# How to extract records which are between specified hours of the day in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table of Orders, and it has a field called OrderDateTime.

I want to apply two filters on my query:

1. Extracting orders which have happened from a given `fromDate` to the given `toDate`
2. Only showing orders which have happened from a given `fromTime` up to the given `toTime`

For example, the query might be:

> Show last week orders which have happened only from 10 in the morning up to 2'o clock after noon

What I've done now is this query:

```
return Orders
       .Where(o => o.OrderDateTime > fromDate
                && o.OrderDateTime < toDate
                && o.OrderDateTime.Hour > fromTime.Hours
                && o.OrderDateTime.Minute > fromTime.Minutes
                && o.OrderDateTime.Hour > toTime.Hours
                && o.OrderDateTime.Minute > toTime.Minutes
             );
```

But I don't get any record, while I do have orders in that time. What's wrong with my query?

Note: `fromTime` and `toTime` are `TimeSpan` objects.

Comment: You realize that you've got `>` instead of `<` on your `toTime.Hours` and `toTime.Minutes`, right?

Comment: i completely forgot about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx   This was a good reminder.... +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first answer is to use

```
return Orders
  .Where(o => o.OrderDateTime > fromDate
      && o.OrderDateTime < toDate
      && o.OrderDateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes > fromTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes
      && o.OrderDateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes < toDate.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes
   );
```

!!!!! BUT WAIT, IT'S NOT WORK ON LINQ TO ENTITY !!!!!

because Linq to entity does not support TimeOfDay!

ok nop. my solusion is to calculate TimeOfDay in a specified units for example Minutes or  Seconds or Milisecends...
for your problem I think minute is good.

```
return Orders
  .Where(o => 
      o.OrderDateTime > fromDate && o.OrderDateTime < toDate
      && (
          o.OrderDateTime.Hours * 60 + o.OrderDateTime.Minutes
           > 
          fromTime.Hours * 60 + fromTime.Minutes
         )
      && (
         o.OrderDateTime.Hours * 60 + o.OrderDateTime.Minutes
          <
          toTime.Hours * 60 + toTime.Minutes
         )
   );
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

First issue is that you use `>` in stead of `<`. At first glance it should be:

```
    ...
    && o.OrderDateTime.Hour < toTime.Hours
    && o.OrderDateTime.Minute < toTime.Minutes
);
```

But that excludes *all* data with minutes < `toTime.Minutes`, also the ones that are before `toTime.Hours`. So you must do this:

```
&& o.OrderDateTime.Hour * 100 + o.OrderDateTime.Minute 
       > fromTime.Hours * 100 + fromTime.Minutes
&& o.OrderDateTime.Hour * 100 + o.OrderDateTime.Minute
         < toTime.Hours * 100 + toTime.Minutes
```

And for EF you must make variables of `fromTime.Hours * 100 + fromTime.Minutes` and `toTime.Hours * 100 + toTime.Minutes` and put those in the linq statement.

Maybe you should use `>=` and `<=` for the hour and minute comparisons.

Comment: see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx canonical functions for linq

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted this:

```
    return Orders
   .Where(o => o.OrderDateTime > fromDate
            && o.OrderDateTime < toDate
            && o.OrderDateTime.Hour > fromTime.Hours
            && o.OrderDateTime.Minute > fromTime.Minutes
            && o.OrderDateTime.Hour < toTime.Hours
            && o.OrderDateTime.Minute < toTime.Minutes
         );
```

Last two < signs were > in your example

@EDIT: Also, why dont you use a DateTime column instead so you can compare all that in a single data variable?

Comment: yep, whether I like your post or not, down votes without an explanation isnt good nor polite practice.  So +1.. if they explain why I may remove the +1.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TimeOfDay`:

```
return Orders
.Where(o => o.OrderDateTime > fromDate
        && o.OrderDateTime < toDate
        && o.OrderDateTime.TimeOfDay > fromTime
        && o.OrderDateTime.TimeOfDay < toTime 
     );
```

Comment: We can not use TimeOfDay in linq to entity